# Is "safes" an acceptable alternative to "makes safe"

Tags: word-usage, tenses, verb-forms

Though I know it's uncommon usage (and intentionally so).  Is the follow sentence legitimate?

> She safes the dangerous area so it cannot be stumbled upon.

Obviously, modern usage would be "she makes safe", but some research on my part shows that "safes" is an acceptable "third-person singular simple present" form of safe.

Am I correct?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll spend more time explaining that you didn't mean "saves" than you gain by replacing "makes safe"

Comment: You could use 'safeguards' or 'secures' if you just want one word.

Comment: Can you give example sentences (author/date/links if possible) from your research?

Comment: Wouldn't "secures" do much the same job?

Comment: Why bother with archaisms in industrial contexts? Also, you do not mean **stumbled upon**, which means to **come upon by chance**. You mean: so no one falls over junk (objects) on the floor.

Comment: @Lambie The OED documents this usage as live up through 2009, and it does not label this obsolete nor archaic as you would allege. Just because their first citation is from 1602 doesn't make it archaic, particularly given their citations from after the 19th century. If you have evidence to the contrary from a citable published resource, I'm sure we'd be interested in seeing it. I bet the OED would, too.

Comment: As a native speaker of English I had never heard "safe" used as a verb until reading this Q&A. That's how rare this usage is, and that's what makes this an interesting question. However, based on sas08's answer, I don't think you can "safe" an area, unless that area is one big weapon. ;-)

Comment: @Mentalist, it's totally commonplace and ordinary around guns, and, say, in the military.  This is the confusing issue with "obscure" words, like, it would "only" be an everyday term to let's say 50 million English speakers.

Comment: As people are requesting more context this is for a fantasy setting, and specifically it's to say that a magical trap, while not disabled is no longer able to cause harm.  As people are mentioning technical usage, firearms and mechanical, this seems appropriate. Thanks all!

Comment: In your specific sentence, I would go with *renders safe*. Render Safe Procedures are formal written guides to making something safe. They usually apply to something that can go bang. The acronym RSP is often used as a verb meaning to execute RSP on something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure we only use *safe* as a verb when discussing ordinance or firearms. There might be other domains (operations security maybe?) but by the verb *safe* we definitely mean operating a safety mechanism designed to keep the weapon from being firing/detonating.

The military definition is provided at [The Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/safing), with citation to the [US DOD](http://jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/dictionary.pdf) (PDF).

> As applied to weapons and ammunition, the changing from a state of readiness for initiation to a safe condition. Also called de-arming.

Comment: @user067531 you may note both examples you found are gun related. As are all the ones I can find on google. Hard too prove it hasn't been used outside those domains... but all I get for "safing" is articles on nukes and aircraft cannons.
For instance:
https://books.google.com/books?id=UDQYAAAAYAAJ&pg=SA2-PA5&lpg=SA2-PA5&dq=safing+a+gun&source=bl&ots=W_9SPHgkkk&sig=ACfU3U0rgRIvyvblYYdFvTNDf-Hb7vJJcg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi13JvHk-_jAhXOmuAKHdGCAfIQ6AEwCnoECBQQAQ#v=onepage&q=safing%20a%20gun&f=false

Comment: That wouldn’t  make it a common usage, but a jargon one.

Comment: @user067531 I'm not sure what you mean by *jargon*. Why would jargon oppose the sense of *common*?

Comment: The other answer shows use with rockets, but perhaps the overlap between military and space organizations resulted in adopting their language.

Comment: The common theme to these examples would seem to be that, for any sort of device that is inherently hazardous in its normal operation, and for which there is some standard procedure for putting it into a non-hazardous state, this usage of "safe" is a technical term referring to that procedure. This is how I've always understood it -- even in ordinary usage, it has a connotation of not just making something "safe" in effect, but doing so by following an officially correct procedure.

Answer (score 10):

***[Safe](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/safe#English)*** as a verb is quite uncommon, Wiktionary is one of the very few  sources to show a few usage examples:

> (transitive) To make something safe.
>
> - 2007, Rocky Raab, Mike Five Eight: Air War Over Cambodia: Air War Over Cambodia
>     *“It just trails behind the pylon until I land, then Cramer removes it when he safes the rocket pods. No evidence of anything when I taxi back inside the compound.”*
> - 2012, Erik Seedhouse, Interplanetary Outpost
>     *One of the most important events after touchdown will be to safe the Dauntless, which will include purging the engines and shutting down the landing systems […]*

Comment: Not common, but it does get used: John always safes his gun before putting it away. Leslie is far less careful. "Let me just safe my gun" said John. Guns usually come with safety locks, so the usage is quite specific.

Comment: It's not uncommon, it's just common only in a technical domain that requires the operation of mechanical safeties.

Comment: It is very uncommon and here can clearly be seen to be weapon-related or space-vehicule related.

Comment: The OED attests this usage with citations from 1602 up through 2009. It belongs to their frequency band 3, which comprises 20% of the non-obsolete terms in the dictionary, and whose "Verbs tend to be either colloquial or technical, e.g. *emote, mosey, josh, recapitalize.*"

Comment: @Cascabel I did not vote for closure. I am merely saying that in the civilian world it is not common. That is a fact. But tell me, would you say it for the context provided by the OP? Some find of factory floor? I doubt it...

Comment: @Lambie: One might "safe" a piece of equipment to prevent it from being accidentally started with potentially dangerous consequences.  The OP's usage isn't quite right, but that may be because the example is over-simplified.

Answer (score 0):

**safeguard** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/safeguard))

> Definition of safeguard (Entry 2 of 2)
>   transitive verb
>
> 1 : to provide a safeguard for
>
> **2 : to make safe : PROTECT**

**secure** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secure))

> Definition of secure (Entry 2 of 2)
>   transitive verb
>
> 1a : to relieve from exposure to danger : **act to make safe against adverse contingencies**
>   secure a supply line from enemy raids

Comment: The adjective "safe" can be used as an antonym for either "vulnerable" or "dangerous".  The verbs you suggest are only applicable to the first meaning, but the OP's post suggests the second.

Comment: You make a good point, I might have copied the wrong part of the definition. Regardless, I think either option works with the sample sentence.